# How to use refresh div correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick, refresh

**Hi,**

**Can you explain why my refresh div does not work? When clicked submit it seems the div is trying to refresh by removing all rows data but it is then not returning anything which leaves the div blank instead. The data stored to DB fine but I need the div to refresh and show all new submitted data**

```
$('#submitBtm').on('click', onSubmit = () => {

    const first_nameV = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
    const last_nameV = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
    const emailV = document.getElementById("email").value;
    const departmentV = document.getElementById("department").value;
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: `companydirectory/libs/php/insertAll.php?first_name=${first_nameV}&last_name=${last_nameV}&email=${emailV}&departmentID=${departmentV}`,
            success: function(data) {
               
            },
            error:  function(request,error) {
                console.log(request)                                   
            }
        })

        $("#id_data").load(location.href + " #id_data");

    event.preventDefault();
})
```

**on HTML page**

```
<div class="listTable">
     <tbody id="id_data">
                        
     </tbody>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't update because you're not appending the new data that you receive on the success callback

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: `companydirectory/libs/php/insertAll.php?first_name=${first_nameV}&last_name=${last_nameV}&email=${emailV}&departmentID=${departmentV}`,
        success: function(data) {
           // here you have the data and you can refresh the table
        },
        error:  function(request,error) {
            console.log(request)                                   
        }
    })
```

Comment: but there is nothing for me to do as it is just posting new data to the DB? I've tried putting $("#id_data").load(location.href + " #id_data"); inside the success and it still doesn't work...

Comment: How data are you getting on the success response?

Comment: You were right! I've created a function that wrapped around the getAll() data when the app first loads. With this I can just popped the 2 inside the success callback, worked perfectly. Thank you 